# swimlane/ngx-datatable, how to disable checkbox on condition?

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, ngx-datatable

I have 2 issues with swimlane/ngx-datatable.

1. unable to control(enable or disable) the checkbox based on condition.
2. group selection. I followed the below link but i am unable to check the group child when the parent is checked

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-grouping.component.ts

[attaced the screenshot, check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DPLw.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: instead of disabling the library has feature of hiding checkbox with usage of [displayCheck] 
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/selection/selection-chkbox.component.ts

Comment: @Shantanu hope you are referring to this, http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#chkbox-selection, here if you see when you hit select all the hidden checkbox row also getting selected. how to overcome that?

Comment: No man check again the one with name "Ethel Price" is not selected when you click checkbox on header of 1st column. And you can check the condition in displayCheck method here: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/selection/selection-chkbox.component.ts

Comment: For enabling / disabling the checkbox try [select checkbox](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/inputs#selectcheck)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass input to the component and add the `disable` property in the checkbox tag like 
`[disabled]="notEditable === 'true'"`
Or any other condition you need.

Comment: Since links within this question are no longer available, please broaden your answer to be more generic. "Here's how you conditionally add disabled attribute to HTML element in..."